# How to execute --disable-json?

Tags: command-line-interface, raspbian, telegram

Installing the Telegram Agent on Raspberry Pi2 (following Instructables.com)
I'm receiving:

```
configure: error: No libjansson found. Try --disable-json
```

How to execute this recommendation and eliminate the error?

Answer (score 1):

They mean "add the `--disable-json` option to the ./configure call", I would say like

```
./configure <maybe more options> --disable-json
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, DummyGuy - here we expect that you "accept" answers given to you that solve the question. (klick on the check mark)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need this library, can ignore and disable it by this command:

```
# ./configure --disable-json
```

But I suggest to you install `jansson` library from this guide: ([reference](https://jansson.readthedocs.io/en/1.1/gettingstarted.html))

If you use debian base distro:

```
# sudo apt-get install libjansson-dev
```

Otherwise you can compile from source with these command:

```
# wget http://www.digip.org/jansson/releases/jansson-2.10.tar.gz
# tar xvfz jansson-2.10.tar.gz
# cd jansson-2.10
# ./configure
# make
# make install
# autoreconf –vi
```